# read different types of image files

Tags: matlab

i know how to read all the image files from a folder which are of the same type, e.g `TIFF`. My question: is there any way to read all kinds of image files in a folder? The images can be `TIFF`, `BMP`, `JPEG`. It may also happen that at a given point only `JPEGs` are present in the folder or maybe all three types are there.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the function `imread` can read most of the existing standard image types.
So, what you can do is

```
cd( folder );
fls = dir( '*' ); % list ALL files
ii = 1;
imgs = {};
for fi=1:numel(fls)
    if fls(fi).isdir, continue; end; % skip sub directories
    try
       tmp = imread( fls(fi).name );
       imgs{ii} = tmp; % got an image
       ii = ii+1; 
    catch em
       % not an image - ignore
    end
 end
```